# Optional all capture groups in rewrite rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have created page-images.php, inside that file I have some code with Template name, in dashboard I have created page Slike and chose that template... all that is working.

I have added rewrite rule just as it is described here and I have flushed permalinks https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

```
function pl_add_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^slike/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=45893&carstvo=$matches[1]&kategorija=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'pl_add_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Now these urls work:

- localhost/mysite/slike
- localhost/mysite/slike/biljke/cvijece

But this doesn't

- localhost/mysite/slike/biljke

In Codex it says that capture groups are optional. Do I have to do something else to make it work? I want to have all 3 kinds of urls working

```
$regex
(string) (required) A regular expression to match against a requested URL.
 This can optionally use one or more capture groups.
```

Comment: what is optional is the use of capture groups not the catching in the regex. you can us this website to construct the regex you need : https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Ok after 4 hours I managed to make it work

```
function pl_add_rewrite_rule() {
    // this works with pagination too
    add_rewrite_rule('^slike(\/([a-z]+))?(\/([a-z]+))?(\/page\/([0-9]+))?$','index.php?page_id=45893&carstvo=$matches[2]&kategorija=$matches[4]&paged=$matches[6]','top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%carstvo%','([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%kategorija%','([^/]*)');
}
add_action('init', 'pl_add_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```